# Finding Printers with bonjour in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, printing, bonjour

I got some requirement to print PDF files directly from my app to shared Printers on my local network (printers may or may not be airprint enabled). I got to know about bonjour and started working on it. According to Apple we have standard service types for printers like

```
_printer._tcp.
_ipp._tcp.
_ipps._tcp.
_pdl-datastream._tcp.
```

I have Richo printer on my network and it's bonjour enabled. With a bonjour browser on my Mac I can see that my richo printer is advertised under `_http._tcp`. But not under any of the above mentioned service types by Apple. Along with this printer there are many more shared machines under `_http._tcp`. My problem is how can I know whether it is a printer or other machine as all of them are listed under `_http._tcp`. ?

When I browse programmatically using above 4 service types nothing comes up which is understandable as the printer is under `_http._tcp`. Is there any way I can get all the printers available listed from local network ?

Thanks.